# Find a CMake file-generating add_custom_command example in which DEPENDS option is necessary

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command

I want a simple example to illustrate the `DEPENDS` option of file generating [`add_custom_command(OUTPUT ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/add_custom_command.html#generating-files), that is, if we comment the `DEPENDS` part, the example will give different output or totally crash.

In the following example (there are files `london` and `good.cpp` in the current working directory), `DEPENDS` is  dispensable:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Tutorial VERSION 1.0)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT foo
COMMAND cp london foo
#DEPENDS london
COMMENT "I'm testing the new method.")

add_executable(cake good.cpp foo)
```

I did read the documentation. I have little knowledge about building system, neither Make nor CMake. The first sentence `Specify files on which the command depends.` confuses me. I don't understand how a command depends on other files, in my casual example, the command line itself seems to locate everything. I want a CMake code example to show how command depends on other files, with the necessary help of DEPENDS.

Comment: @Ysyvarev I gave the casual example just to show some scenario where DEPENDS is dispensable. My goal is to find an example where DEPENDS is really necessary.

Comment: Actually, I find strange a question which tells "the option XXX could be omitted because everything works without it". It is you as a project's developer decide which **functionality** do you need. If desired functionality is provided by the option XXX, then you use the option. If you don't need a functionality, then you don't need to use the option.

Comment: @Tsyvarev You're totally right from the engineering perspective. I'm now learning CMake and want to understand how to make use of this option, I'm not trying to solve a real problem.

Comment: If you want to understand how the option works, then the first place to check is [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html). Have you read it? What is not clear in it? E.g. "If `DEPENDS` is not specified, the command will run whenever the `OUTPUT` is missing; if the command does not actually create the `OUTPUT`, the rule will always run." If you are familiar with Make, then documentation provides Make-view on the dependencies: `OUTPUT: MAIN_DEPENDENCY DEPENDS`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I did read the documentation. I have little knowledge about building  system, neither Make nor CMake. The first sentence `Specify files on which the command depends. ` confuses me. I don't understand how a command depends on other files, in my casual example, the command line itself seems to locate everything. I want a CMake code example to show how command depends on other files, with the necessary help of `DEPENDS`.

Comment: Well, your [last comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69987498/find-a-cmake-file-generating-add-custom-command-example-in-which-depends-option?noredirect=1#comment123719209_69987498) seems to state your **actual problem**. Please, incorporate it into the **question post** (On Stack Overflow a question post should be understandable without reading the comments. The comments themselves are "secondary citizen".)

Comment: `I don't understand how a command depends on other files` Wouldn't you want `foo` to change when `london` is changed? Development is about editing files, you edit `london` and recompile your project - so you expect `foo` to be changed, and `cake` to be changed. Without `DEPENDS`, nothing will be done, because cmake will not know anything changed.

Comment: @KamilCuk Your comment helps me truly understand the function of `DEPENDS`! Awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase in documentation

> Specify files on which the command depends.

is better understandable as

> Specify files on which **content** of the command's **output file**(s) depends.

As one could guess, a content of the output file of the command `cp london foo`  depends only from `london`, so it is reasonable to specify option `DEPENDS london` for `add_custom_command`.

As a build system, CMake uses information in DEPENDS for decide, whether to run the command or not. If:

- `OUTPUT` file has already been created on previous run, and
- since previous run the `DEPENDS` file has not been updated,

then the command won't be run again. The reasoning is simple: no needs to run the command if it results with the same file(s).

---

Taking into account source (`CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`) and build (`CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`) directories separation, the example could be rewritten as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Tutorial VERSION 1.0)

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT foo # relative path denotes a file in the build directory
  COMMAND cp ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/london foo # The command will be run from the build directory,
    # so need to use absolute path for the file in the source directory
  DEPENDS london # relative path is resolved in the source directory,
    # assuming that corresponded file is already existed
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} # specifies a directory from which run the COMMAND
    # build directory is used by default, so the option can be omitted
  COMMENT "I'm testing the new method."
)

add_executable(cake
  good.cpp # relative path is resolved in the source directory,
    # assuming that corresponded file is already existed
  foo # because given file is absent in the source directory,
    # the path is resolved relative to the build directory.
)
```

When build the project the first time, both `foo` and executable will be built.

When build the project the second time (without changing in `london`) nothing will be rebuilt.

When change `london` file and build the project again, `foo` will be re-built (because it depends on `london`). As `foo` is rebuilt, the executable will be rebuilt too, because it depends on `foo`.